# Simplify for loop without a lot of if-else cases

Tags: c, for-loop

I should output:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

And I did output that but my code is too complicated for that kind of exercise:

```
for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
  if (i == 6) {
    printf("******\n");
  } else {
    if (i == 5) {
      printf("*****\n");
    } else {
      if (i == 4) {
        printf("****\n");
      } else {
        if (i == 3) {
          printf("***\n");
        } else {
          if (i == 2) {
            printf("**\n");
          } else {
            if (i == 1) {
              printf("*\n");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see there are a lot of if-else cases to look which value `i` contains and then to decide how many of the symbols per line should be output, but this code is just a massive block of code which, I think, is not necessarily needed. So I came here to ask, how to simplify my code with the same result.

The code should just look a bit more readable. Any idea how to change my code in my case?

Comment: remove all lines which are not `printf` and it will be nice ;)

Comment: @Michal Walenciak Great!, make an answer!

Comment: @MichałWalenciak ;), theoretically I could do that but I had to do it with a loop and it would not be looking as good as with a loop haha.

Comment: @Mike That would be the funniest answer I have ever seen xD.

Comment: @D.Dave: I'm afraid this answer would not be understood and I would be downvoted ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a nested loop. That's a loop within a loop. To get your desired output, try this:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6 - i; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here, the `i` loop is responsible for the rows (you can see the `printf("\n");` that gets run every time) and the `j` loop is responsible for printing the appropriate amount of `"*"`.

Comment: That is exactly what I looked for. In seven minutes I will mark your answer! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

If you use another `for` loop it will be a lot simpler:

```
for(int i = 6; i > 0;i--) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {  
     printf("*");
    }  
    printf("\n");
   }
```